# Ionic 3 : geolocation isn't stable across the different Android versions

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I'm working on an Ionic project based on **geolocation** and after testing my App on four real devices, I distinguished three different behaviors:

1) **Android 4.x** ( J1 Samsung) => works Correctly

2) **Android 5.0.1** => The first time I install the App all works as expected but when I disable GPS and enable it again, the geolocation returns a position which is far about 1Km of my position and it still bugged until I restart the Phone and then it works correctly again until I restart GPS.

3) **Android 5.1** => Same scenario of the Android 5.0.1 but after turning GPS OFF and enabling it again, the geolocation still returning an error "timeout" until I restart the Phone.

Please, I have to know if there is no solution or I can continue with this plugin?

> Home.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

declare const google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private platform:Platform,
              private geolocation:Geolocation) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.initMap();
        resolve();
      },2000);
    })
    .then(()=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.getGeolocation();
      },2000);
    });
  }


  initMap() {
    // map implementation
  }

  getGeolocation(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      alert('start geolocation');
      var options = {
        timeout: 20000,
        enableHighAccuracy:true,
      };

      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(resp => {
        alert('done');
        console.log(resp.coords.latitude);
        console.log(resp.coords.longitude);
        let origin = new google.maps.LatLng( resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
        this.addMarker(origin);  
        this.map.setCenter(origin);
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.debugError(error); 
        alert('error geoloc');
      });

    });
  }

addMarker(location) {
   //addMarker implementation
}

  debugError(object){
    var output = '';
    for (var property in object) {
      output += property + ': ' + object[property]+'; ';
    }
    alert(output);
    console.log(output);
  }
}
```

> ionic info:

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.9.4
npm               : 5.7.1 
OS                : Linux 4.13
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : xxx
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.9.4
npm               : 5.7.1 
OS                : Linux 4.13
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME: xxx/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend: pro
```

Comment: There is been issue with geolocation plugin in android. you can get help by reading this blog post  https://blog.ionicframework.com/testing-geolocation-on-android/

Comment: @AbineshJoyel This article is about Android Emulator geolocation issues But My Problem is about real devices.

Comment: im encoutering this too..  anyone already have a solution?